# Vuejs 2: debounce not working on a watch option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, debouncing

When I debounce this function in VueJs it works fine if I provide the number of milliseconds as a primitive.  However, if I provide it as a reference to a prop, it ignores it.

Here's the abbreviated version of the props:

```
props : {
    debounce : {
        type : Number,
        default : 500
    }
}
```

Here is the watch option that does NOT work:

```
watch : {
    term : _.debounce(function () {
        console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
    }, this.debounce)
}
```

Here is a watch option that DOES work:

```
watch : {
    term : _.debounce(function () {
        console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
    }, 500)
}
```

It suspect that it is a scope issue but I don't know how to fix it.  If I replace the watch method as follows...:

```
watch : {
    term : function () {
        console.log(this.debounce);
    }
}
```

... I get the correct debounce value (500) appearing in the console.

Comment: It is a scope issue. You can define `this.$watch` inside a lifecycle hook like `created`, then you'll receive the correct value for `this.debounce`. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue here is using `this.debounce` as the interval when defining your debounced function. At the time `_.debounce(...)` is run (when the component is being compiled) the function is not yet attached to the Vue, so `this` is *not* the Vue and `this.debounce` will be undefined. That being the case, you will need to define the watch after the component instance has been created. Vue gives you the ability to do that using [$watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch).

I would recommend you add it in the created lifecycle handler.

```
created(){
  this.unwatch = this.$watch('term', _.debounce((newVal) => {
     console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
  }, this.debounce))
},
beforeDestroy(){
  this.unwatch()
}
```

Note above that the code also calls `unwatch` which before the component is destroyed. This is typically handled for you by Vue, but because the code is adding the watch manually, the code also needs to manage removing the watch. Of course, you will need to add `unwatch` as a data property.

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("debounce",{
  props : {
    debounce : {
      type : Number,
      default : 500
    }
  },
  template:`
    <input type="text" v-model="term">
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      unwatch: null,
      term: ""
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.unwatch = this.$watch('term', _.debounce((newVal) => {
      console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
    }, this.debounce))
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    this.unwatch()
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <debounce :debounce="250"></debounce>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another variation to @Bert's answer is to build the watcher's function in `created()`,

```js
// SO: Vuejs 2: debounce not working on a watch option

console.clear()

Vue.component("debounce",{
  props : {
    debounce : {
      type : Number,
      default : 500
    }
  },
  template:`
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="term">
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      term: "",
      debounceFn: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.debounceFn = _.debounce( () => {
      console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
    }, this.debounce)
  },
  watch : {
    term : function () {
      this.debounceFn();
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <debounce :debounce="2000"></debounce>
</div>
```

Example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/mqOabd)

Answer (score 2):

The `debounced method` needs to be abstracted since we need to call the same function everytime the `watch` is triggered.  If we place the `debounced` method inside a `Vue` `computed` or `watch` property, it will be *renewed* everytime.

```js
const debouncedGetData = _.debounce(getData, 1000);

function getData(val){
  this.newFoo = val;
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model="foo" placeholder="Type something..." />
      <pre>{{ newFoo }}</pre>
    </div>
`,
    data(){
      return {
        foo: '',
        newFoo: ''
      }
    },
    watch:{
      foo(val, prevVal){
        debouncedGetData.call(this, val);
      }
    }
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#term',
  data: function() {
    return {
      term: 'Term',
      debounce: 1000
    }
  },
  watch: {
    term : _.debounce(function () {
        console.log('Debounced term: ' + this.term);
    }, this.debounce)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="term">
  <input v-model="term">
</div>
```