# Vue JS - Issue with watching multiple data at once

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have included a multiple watcher in one of my components.In computed property,

```
   changeData() {
     const { propA, propB } = this
     return {
       propA,
       propB,
     }
   },
```

In watch,

```
changeData: {
  handler: function(val) {
    //Execute
  },
  deep: true
}
```

So, the issue being. Whenever one of the two data changes, callback function is called as expected.

But, suppose I have a flag set, using which I am calling an API and assigning data to these variables, I don't know how many times these get executed.

I want to know when the watcher stops after data from API is assigned to respective variables. I need to perform an operation, once watcher stops.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean, by example? The description is ambiguous

Comment: Could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172952/vuejs-2-debounce-not-working-on-a-watch-option or something else

Comment: @EstusFlask Main idea behind this, I have to toggle a button if one the variables, say X, Y, Z changes. Hence I added watcher on multiple variables.  I am having a wizard, after I hit an API from step 1. Let's say I get back a variable which I store in component's data. I move to step 2, then come back to step 1. I want all the data to be present there which were processed in step 1. So i hit an API with an ID and get the data. Since I have added watcher for X, Y, Z, it get hits multiple times. My requirement being, I have to know when all these watcher actions are over. To be continued...

Comment: Whenever variables are getting assigned, obviously watcher gets called. So I want to know how to handle the issue I mentioned above. I want to execute certain function once everything is done

Comment: Seems like you need debounced watcher for that, as in the link above